# Does Parse.Cloud.beforeRead exist is some form?

Tags: parse-platform

In Parse there is something called:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave
```

I wonder if there is something to play the role of a:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeRead
```

I need a way to control what is going to be returned to the user when a request is made to the DB.
In particular in certain circomstances, depending on information on the server, I want to force blank fields in the result of the DB request made by the user. Any standard way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `Parse.Cloud.beforeRead` kind of function supported by Parse.

Instead, you can define a custom cloud function using

`Parse.Cloud.define('readObjects', function(request, response) {...} );`

that returns array of objects. This function will act as a wrapper over the Parse query. 
Then, your client apps should be calling this cloud function to fetch objects rather than direct Parse.Query requests.

Comment: I see. In this case I will try that. Thanks.